# how to set xib in uitabBarItem in iphone

Tags: iphone

I made a uitabBarItem in iphone.How can i set the xib in uitabBarItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize an UITabBarItem and set the relative xib you can follow [this tutorial](http://praxisstalled.blogspot.com/2010/08/customising-appearance-of.html).

Comment: can we not set xib programmatically.

Comment: But i need to set it programmatically because i made button programmatically.